# Problem with Iframe, Header and footer is over the iframe

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I made wordpress page templete, and it works.
My problem is when I make the iframe responsive, the footer and header become over the iframe as you can see from this page
https://testdomain.com/html
What I'm doing wrong?

I want the footer to stuck at the end of the iframe after the iframe completely stretched
So it will look like it's one page
This is what I have tried:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: templatename
 */
get_header();?>
<style>
iframe {
 position:fixed; 
 top:0; 
 left:0; 
 bottom:0; 
 right:0; 
 width:100%; 
 height:100%; 
 border:none; 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0;
}
</style>

<div class="iframe">
<iframe src="https://testdomain.com/html/newpage/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The link that you have provided doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the iframe css style
The issue is at Header & Footer css
Remove any position style from header and footer, and let us know

Comment: I tried, still the same